Siding corner dilemma - no soffit
[I was replacing the ply and noticed water getting behind the siding from top and from the corners. What is the best way to install siding on corners and top in this situation?
Background: 1. Roof of this shed had rubber Added shingles but noticed wetness at the far outside corner and also water getting in through the floor next to the front entrance of this shed.
2. place where the electric cable enters was rotting 1/4 inch wall panelling, replaced it with 5/8 treated plywood.
Extra material on hand right now: vinyl j channel 12 feet, one panel of vinyl siding, synthetic roof underlayment, 1 1/4 siding nails.


Have you figured out where the water is coming from?

I am assuming from the corner channel

I think I'd get some Z-metal (window flashing) and put it over both the corner channel and the top course of siding (which I assume will be in a starter channel). It would fit behind the fascia, ideally, but you could use something with less depth and put it over your fascia and behind the drip edge flange.

image source
Another approach would be to cut away the back portion of the corner channel so you can slide the face up behind the drip edge. You could maybe slide the top course of siding up behind the fascia. Now everything drains properly.

If the facia and rakes are the same size as the one in the picture, I would get more corner trim like you have in place already, but cut it at the corner. That way it will be able to tuck up under the drip edge, cover the fascia and the perforated edge will nail back to the face of the plywood just like the corner does.


This will give a drip edge over the siding so it will not take on water like the original did that only met the fascia.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Georgia-Pacific-Outside-Corner-Post-White-3-in-x-120-in-Vinyl-Siding-Trim/999969100 . This is what they have. Isn't this what I have at the corner? I can also get a z channel like suggested above.

Yes that is what you have at the corner. The Z flashing, in my opinion will not work for the top where the water is getting in. The corner piece like in the picture of the link you have, if it is cut at the corner, the highest part in the picture, the cut edge when done well, will go under the drip edge and keep any water from getting behind it.... if it is tall enough. The other edge where the nails go will act as a J channel, but now you have fascia material, and J channel all in one piece where no water can get between joints of 2 separate pieces.

So cut the corner piece i have in such a pointy way that it tucks under the drip edge. If it is not tall enough then get a new one?

I don't know if pointy way is how it would be. I will make a sketch to show where the cut should be and how I hope it could fit to the roof in your situation.

So when I cut where the line is, it will separate the corner piece in two parts along its vertical length. I will now have two j channels essentially from the corner trim. I will now take the siding out from the adjacent wall out from the other cut corner piece. Move both cut corner pieces up and under the drip edge. Is this correct?

During the rains for the past few days, I noticed water getting through into the shed floor where the door is. Wind was driving rain under the door. Any suggestions here? This is the second dilemma. I plan on installing some polycarb panels soon over the back door of the house. Back door to the house and shed share a common concrete deck about 4x4 feet.

Perhaps that needs to be posed as another question since I will need pictures to see accurately what you have now to give the best answer. Stack Exchange typically only allows a one question format. There can be different questions regarding the same issue. This question is entirely separate from the original question.
